# Not able to search based on tag in career site

Tags: bug, status-completed, firefox, error-message, jobs

I tried to search openings for [python](/questions/tagged/python) and give `[python]` in **Keywords**.

This gives error

[image: StackOveflow Job Portal error]

I am using Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu 45.0.

If I search without tag, then its working, like if I search for `Python` (without bracket) it gives result.

Comment: Where exactly are you searching? The screenshot shows careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, searching with `python` or `[python]` - are you running any extensions/add-ons (try disabling them and search again)?

Comment: I clicked on `Jobs` button and that give this. Now I am not able to reproduce, because I link Career and Jobs :(. So If I click on careers, it moved to jobs.

Comment: So, can you search for python jobs now?

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to open Career site :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an outage around the time you reported this causing the error.

This has since been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to understand and reply :)